# How Change Auto Formatting HTML In Visual Studio 2008 2010

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, formatting

The auto formatter doesnt seem to be as configurable for HTML as it is for C#.

When I type `<div>`

I get 
`<div>|</div>`

I want

```
<div>
    |
</div>
```

Thoughts?

*UPDATE - I have ReSharper installed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tool -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Format -> Tag Specific Options... -> Client HTML Tags -> div

Note the Line breaks: section; as well as a preview at the bottom.

Keep in mind this has to do with the formatting option of the HTML file itself; NOT how auto complete and IntelliSense operate within VS. Therefore without ReSharper I can go start an open div and close it and will get what you describe within the HTML document...

```
<div></div>
```

If I were to change that to...

```
<div><button></button></div>
```

...and hit CTRL+K, CTRL+D I would get...

```
<div>
    <button>
    </button>
</div>
```

...which is where the formatting begins to surface.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking at.  Perhaps is being overwritten by ReSharper settings?  I will investigate further.

Comment: This isnt the exact sln I was hoping for, but it does yield the desired result.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Scott Gu has a posting on how to do it.  Sceenshot are there too.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/07/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Custom-formatting-HTML-in-Visual-Web-Developer-and-Visual-Studio-2005.aspx