# Visual Studio 2010 Auto-Formatting ASPX maladies

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, code-formatting

Alright. I've done a LOT of searching around, and found many posts that *address* this issue, but do not actually have any resolutions.

Visual Studio 2010 really likes auto-formatting my code. This is all great and wonderful, when it's actually doing what I tell it to.
Whilst editing an .aspx file, formatting does not work well for me. So I try to place spaces before and after all my closing tags and `Format Document` (ctrl+k,Ctrl+d or Ctrl+e,d), and it will format it according to the `Tag Specific Options...` in `Text Editor->HTML->Formatting`, which I have obsessively set, checked, and double-checked.
Apparently the requirement of leading and trailing spaces for formatting [was a design decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639606/html-formatting-in-visual-studio-2010), although it's lost on me as to why, since most whitespace is ignored in parsing of normal html documents. Whatever, I can deal, I just need to put in a ton of extra spaces, then it will do it right, right? In short: no.
**Point being:** After I've taken pains to make sure that it is formatting everything the way I have it set to, by putting a ton of extra spaces in my markup and `Format Document`ing, like so:

```
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
            </div>
            <div id="Week2Summary" align="right">
                Week 2 - Summary
            </div>
            <br />
            <div id="PayPeriod" align="right">
                Pay Period- Summary
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlTimeModify" runat="server" Visible="False" borderColor="#009900"
            Width="100%">
```

whenever I switch to the designer view, save, or sometimes just look at it wrong, it takes out all of the spaces, reformats, and screws it all up:

```
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table></div><div id="Week2Summary" align="right">
            Week 2 - Summary </div><br /><div id="PayPeriod" align="right">
            Pay Period- Summary </div></div><br /><asp:Panel ID="pnlTimeModify" runat="server" Visible="False" BorderColor="#009900"
                Width="100%">
```

So, I've installed PowerCommands and Productivity Power Tools, one of whom adds a "format on save" setting that is defaulted to off. Great! Restart, and it seems to work great. Reboot a couple times, and it's doing it again. Now I'm about to blow up the computer and walk out of the office. I'll save the rant for some other place.

**In Short:** I need to know how to make VS either:

- stop formatting automatically whenever it feels like it
- stop taking out my spaces that force formatting to work correctly when it does
- or stop requiring the extra spaces in the first place

so I can work in peace again. (I'm sure the girls down the hall are getting sick of my periodic screaming.)

**What I've tried:**

- Set formatting settings in Text Editor->HTML->Formatting->Tag Specific Options...
- Install PowerCommands and Productivity Power Tools and edit the settings to "prevent" formatting on save
- Use extra spaces to force formatting to work properly (which are taken out automatically by VS whenever I save or switch views)
- Change the File Extensions options so that .aspx are opened as XML and HTML documents, neither helping at all.

However, it continues to raise my blood pressure. Thanks for any help you can give me. I'm going to go have lunch and try to calm down.

Answer (score 0):

was having the same problem, and I found the answer on Scott Gu's blog.

The solution is to setup the formatting rules in Visual Studio (right click on any tag, click on Formatting and Validation, click on Tag Specific Options)

When press ctrl-k, ctrl-d the document will format as per your settings. If a closing tag does not move to a ne.w line, it's because there is no space between the end tag and what is preceding it. This happens because Visual Studio is being careful to not change how the page is rendered.

For the full blog post checkout Scott Gu's blog post.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/07/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Custom-formatting-HTML-in-Visual-Web-Developer-and-Visual-Studio-2005.aspx

Comment: The trick is: I've done this, and I do put an extra space at the end of what I want to be a line. However, the visual studio formatting removes the extra space at the end of the line automatically which causes my newlines get removed by the auto-format.