# ASP.NET Title Tag has Carriage Return

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I set the Title Tag of a page in ASP.NET, it adds carriage returns which is unneccessary, is there any way in .NET to remove the carriage returns.  It happens when I create a new website, not just the site I've been developing.

```
<title>
    The Title of the Page
</title>
```

Should really be

```
<title>The Title of the Page</title>
```

Viagogo.com kind of gets rid of the first carriage return, not the second so there must be a way.  If it needs a coding solution, C# would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingViewStateToTheBottomOfThePage.aspx which I amended to minify and remove the line breaks from the title tag by adding in replace statements to remove the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This has really nothing to do with .net.
It's a document formatting thing, and differs from IDE to IDE. Often helper software such as resharper formats a document according to a set of rules and standards, making documents easier for others to read.

Most IDEs lets you edit the way you want this to be automatically generated, if you want any at all.

Also, see the [following SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403237/how-change-auto-formatting-html-in-visual-studio-2008-2010) for a similar issue.

Comment: I am using VSE2013 and I just format everything as it should look when its  compiled.  I remove the title tag and set the title with Page.Title = 'Home Page"; but still puts carriage returns in it...

Comment: If this is a problem, then you need to start tweeking the rules a bit. I'd take a look in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor (From the left menu).

Comment: I added a link to a relevant post in my answer.

Comment: No, not IDE, its when the asp.net has been compiled that carriage returns are added.  If I wrote the page in Notepad, i still expect to see carriage returns which I don't want.

Comment: Ah, ok. I have no clue how to change that :) Do you mind if I ask why you need this functionality? :) Sounds to me like you want to "minify" it after build.

Comment: Correct, i'm trying to minify it and I see CR in a title as being a negative feature when a SE reads the title.  I maybe wrong but with 200+ signals Google uses, I couldn't say for definite whether CR in a title is bad or ignored.